# Open all links on page in new tabs and track those tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I know I cannot directly access the DOM from the main function in a firefox addon with the SDK, and therefore I cannot obtain the href values from the a tags directly either. How can I make my addon open all of the links on a page as new tabs and add those to an array? I don't want new tabs manually opened by the user to be tracked, just the ones created by this addon.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If we are going to try to verify our solution works for you it is MUCH easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you.

Comment: You can access the content of a page with a Firefox Addon's content script. If you provide more info as @Makyen said, we can help you.

Comment: @Makyen I've asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29748993/3249111). could you help me If you have any idea on that.

Answer (score 1):

Partially solved the issue a while back so I figure I'll point out what I know.

Since the main script can't access the DOM itself, it can instead attach a worker to the current tab. The worker can read all of the links and store them as a list, then send that list back to the add-on. The add-on can then open new tabs directed at all the links in that list.

In main, add a content script to the tab:

```
function attachScript() {
  var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("content-script.js")
  });
  worker.port.on("links", function(links) {
    for each(var l in links) {
        tabs.open(l);
    }
  }); // Start listening for links sent by the tab's worker
  worker.port.emit("get-links"); // Request links from worker
}
```

In the content script, upon receiving a get-links message, read all the links and send them back using port:

```
self.port.on("get-links", handleMessage); // Start listening for requests for links on page

function handleMessage(message) {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // Get all a elements on page
  alert(anchors.length); // Report quantity of a elements found
  var hrefs = [];
  for each (var a in anchors) {
    hrefs.push(a.href); // Add all target urls of a elements to array
  }
  self.port.emit("links", hrefs); // Send array of urls to add-on script
}
```

As for tracking the tabs, I imagine keeping a list of the workers would be the appropriate way to accomplish this. I haven't tried that part yet as I had to put this project down for a while.