# How to load multiple URLS in pageWorker for Firefox add-on SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Using the following example, I can get First paragraph from one URL i.e, `ContentURL`. ex - `http://www.example.com`

```
//main.js 
var getFirstParagraph = "var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');" +
                        "console.log(paras[0].textContent);" 

pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
  contentScript: getFirstParagraph,
  contentURL: "http://www.example.com"
});
```

I would like to get the first paragraph for multiple site URLs.

```
var urls = ["http://www.example.com", "http://www.example1.com", "http://www.example2.com"]
```

Is there any way to load multiple URLS to get the multiple results in an array?

I tried like following way, but it goes into infinite loop and doesn't work.

```
//main.js

var getFirstParagraph = "var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');" +
                        "console.log(paras[0].textContent);" +
                        "self.port.emit('loaded');" 


pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
  contentScript: getFirstParagraph,
  contentURL: "http://www.example2.com"
});

pageWorker.port.on("loaded", function() {
var urls = ["http://www.example.com", "http://www.example1.com"];
    for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++)
    {
  pageWorker.contentURL = urls[i];
    }

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've ended up the code like this. It's working good.

```
var getFirstParagraph = "var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');" +
                        "console.log(paras[0].textContent);"

var urls = ["http://www.example.com", "http://www.example2.com"];
for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++)
    {
pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
  contentScript: getFirstParagraph,
  contentURL : urls[i],
});
}
```

I didn't find any better option than this. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @Noitidart My pleasure..Glad to hear that from you. Thanks.